Amazon IVS Integration in Swift
In amazon IVS Live stream integration -
Does the stream automatically end when the streamer moves the app to the background (by checking messages on phone) in amazon IVS broadcast?

⁠if so, is there a way to not end the stream when in app is in background
⁠if there isn’t a way to not end the stream, is there a way for the system to detect this such that the system can let the viewers of the stream (that are using IVS Player SDK) know that the live was ended instead of showing this error message on the viewer side

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
